# Chain rule for $(f(u))'$ when $u \in H^1$ and $f$ is only piecewise Lipschitz?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a peicewise lipschitz function, eg. $f(x) = \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$.

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$. Is the chain rule possible:
$(f(u))' = f'(u)u'$
a.e. or something like that?

I have only seen results for $f$ Lipschitz.

Comment: I think you should try to explain better your problem. What is $u$? Why the tag Sobolev Space and Functional Analysis? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I edited it. I had thought this was a standard result (i.e. someone knows whether it is possible or not) so I did not want to go through adapting the proof for the Lipschitz case to this but maybe I should try that.

Comment: Do you know, that every Sobolev function, is absolutely continuous in a.e. segment of line which is parallel to the coordinate axes?

Comment: This even fails in the 1-dimensional case. Here, every Sobolev function is (absolutely) continuous, but it is easy to construct a smooth (hence Sobolev) function $u$ so that $f \ circ u$ is not continuous (hence not Sobolev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters said, taking  composition with a discontinuous function like $\chi_{(0,1)}$ takes the function out of all Sobolev classes. It no longer has a weak derivative. For most practical purposes, this composition is useless: we threw out the most valuable information about $u$.

But since you asked about derivative a.e., I'll give an example to show that the composition can fail to have that one too. Let $f=\chi_{(0,1)}$ and $u(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,C)$ where $C\in [0,1]$ is a Cantor-type set of positive measure. Then $u$ is Lipschitz, therefore in $H^1$ on $(0,1)$. But $f\circ u = 1-\chi_C$, which is discontinuous at every point of $C$. Hence, the composition is not   differentiable a.e.